# How do I get the "Let's go!" achievement?

Tags: achievements, railway-empire

I was browsing through the Steam achievements for Railway Empire (PC) and observed one called "Let's Go":

[image: Achievement screenshot]

> **Let's go!** First scenario completed successfully

I haven't gotten this achievement, but I have completed several scenarios successfully: I've almost finished the US campaign (still in the middle of "The West"), and have also beaten several scenarios on Free Play (The South as President; France as CEO; and a random map as Stationmaster), and also one of the Scenarios (Black Gold / the South)

What are the criteria for this achievement? Does "first scenario" refer to a specific scenario, or possibly the campaign?

Answer (score 1):

> Each scenario consists of a number of mandatory tasks with a few optional extras.  For each scenario simply complete the mandatory tasks within the time limit and you will complete the scenario.
> However, as each map requires a President rating for the respective trophy, it is advisable to try and complete all the optional tasks as well.

This is an extract from [this trophy guide on PSN Profiles](https://psnprofiles.com/guide/11719-railway-empire-trophy-guide#43-perfectionist).
The achievement is called in a different way, [Here we go](https://psnprofiles.com/trophy/7019-railway-empire/39-here-we-go), but the request is the same.